# WSO2 BPMN: Claimable Task List is Empty

Tags: wso2, bpmn, wso2-esb

I am following this tutorial https://medium.com/@naduni_pamudika/how-to-create-a-simple-bpmn-process-adc94f0b2f86

After completing all steps I am able to see BPMN project but after starting it I am not able to see the project in Claimable Task List or in Completed Task List. Both the lists are empty.

[image]
[image]
[image]
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A task will be considered 'claimable' only if the **Candidate User** or **Candidate Group** of that particular task is specified.

In this case, you have logged in as admin, so setting the Candidate User for the HelloWorld task as 'admin' should set the task as claimable. Any other users that you have defined in the BPS Server should also count as Candidate Users.

You can also have a Claimable task assigned to an entire group of users, by specifying the [User Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA1n7.png). I have defined user roles like 'employee' and 'manager', so setting the Candidate Group as 'employee' will set the task as claimable for all users with the 'employee' role. It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPNqx.png)